# Proper centering with cmidrule and multi- row and column

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow, multicolumn, booktabs

The code below produces the following figure:

[image]

The issue I am having is that `Sample` is not vertically aligned, I get proper alignment if `\cmidrule(l){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}` is removed.

How do I get proper alignment while maintaining the two horizontal lines?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule 
\multirow{2}{*}{Sample} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{I} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{II} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
 & A & B & C & D \\
\midrule
S1 & 5 & 8 & 12 & 2 \\
S2 & 6 & 9 & 2 & 6 \\
S3 & 7 & 9 & 5 & 8 \\
S4 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Off topic: I would use `\cmidrule(lr)` instead of `\cmidrule(l)`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the optional argument of `\multirow`.

Substituting

```
\multirow{2}{*}{Sample}
```

with

```
\multirow{2}[3]{*}{Sample}
```

does what you want.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
\multirow{2}[3]{*}{Sample} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{I} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{II} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
 & A & B & C & D \\
\midrule
S1 & 5 & 8 & 12 & 2 \\
S2 & 6 & 9 & 2 & 6 \\
S3 & 7 & 9 & 5 & 8 \\
S4 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Note that I've also changed `\cmidrule(l)` to `\cmidrule(lr)` for a better looking table, as suggested by Manuel in the comments.

Comment: Why do you give 3 as the optional argument?

Comment: @ondra.cifka In that optional argument you have to try and select the best number that fits...

Answer (score 11):

I had this same problem, and wasn't satisfied with having to guess at the `bigstruts` argument to `\multirow`, so I came up with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]\centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}[-0.5\dimexpr \aboverulesep + \belowrulesep + \cmidrulewidth]{Sample}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{I} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{II} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    & A & B & C & D \\
    \midrule
    S1 & 5 & 8 & 12 & 2 \\
    S2 & 6 & 9 & 2 & 6 \\
    S3 & 7 & 9 & 5 & 8 \\
    S4 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 2 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of above code]

I think this is correct because multirow is already trying to vertically center two rows' worth of height, but you have to account for the extra space added by `\cmidrule`, which adds `\aboverulesep + \cmidrulewidth + \belowrulesep` vertical space.  To accomplish that, we tell `\multirow` to vertically adjust the box downward by half of that `\cmidrule` space.

If it looks a little off center, I *think* that's just an illusion because `\aboverulesep` is smaller than `\belowrulesep`.  I contend that it's "centered" until someone proves me wrong, but you can try `-0.5\dimexpr 2\aboverulesep + \cmidrulewidth` instead and see if you like the look of that better.

While the above solution just fudges the box down, an alternative is probably to set `\bigstrutjot` to `\dimexpr \aboverulesep + \belowrulesep + \cmidrulewidth` and then use `\multirow{2}[1]{*}{Sample}`.  If I understand multirow's documentation, this will actually make the box higher (two rows plus the space added by `\cmidrule`) rather than just moving the box down.  However, in my testing, it yielded the exact same results as the above, and it seems less readable.  (Readability being relative, mind you.)

Comment: just to generalize: `<number-of-cmidrules / 2>\dimexpr \aboverulesep + \belowrulesep + \cmidrulewidth` in case of multiple `\cmidrule`s (+1, btw)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution with `booktabs` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]\centering
\begin{booktabs}{
  colspec = {lcccc},
  cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{m}, % multirow
  cell{1}{2,4} = {c=2}{c}, % multicolumn
}
\toprule 
  Sample & I &   & II &   \\
\cmidrule[l]{2-3} \cmidrule[l]{4-5}
         & A & B & C  & D \\
\midrule
      S1 & 5 & 8 & 12 & 2 \\
      S2 & 6 & 9 &  2 & 6 \\
      S3 & 7 & 9 &  5 & 8 \\
      S4 & 8 & 9 &  8 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{booktabs}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that you need to put trim option `l`, `r` or `lr` inside square brackets.

[image]

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the code: the environment `{booktabs}` should be an environment `{tblr}`. There is also a problem with the commands `\cmidrule`.

Comment: The `booktabs` environment was recently added in version `2021N`.

Answer (score 1):

In the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can merge cells both horizontally and vertically. Vertically, you specify the number of logical rows and not the number of physical lines as in `\multirow`. So the contents of the new (merged) cell is center mathematically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{lcccc}
\toprule 
\Block{2-1}{Sample} & \Block{1-2}{I} & & \Block{1-2}{II} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
         & A & B & C  & D \\
\midrule
      S1 & 5 & 8 & 12 & 2 \\
      S2 & 6 & 9 &  2 & 6 \\
      S3 & 7 & 9 &  5 & 8 \\
      S4 & 8 & 9 &  8 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]